# Doxygen Layout- Can I disable tabs in index but keep them in generated tree view?

Tags: html, css, xml, documentation, doxygen

In the project I am working on I am trying to have both forms of navigation in the documentation, the index and the generated tree.

When looking at the XML layout sheet doxygen helps generate, I am aware that I can turn off visibility of tabs that appear in the index or the generated tree.

My question is since I have NOT disabled the index and set YES to the generated tree, is there a way I can set the visibility of tabs to 'no' just for the index, while have them being able to be viewed on the tree?

Thanks

edit- if anyone is unsure what i mean, I am talking about having both:
DISABLE_INDEX = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW = YES

So if i have both of them, they both are sharing the same tabs in the layout file. I want to know if i can put visibility of certain tabs to NO on the index while having the visibility of those same tags be available in the generated treeview.

Answer (score 3):

No, the layout controls for both the index and the navigation tree generated by doxygen are always the same.